# How to get proper written date using SimpleDateFormat in Java

Tags: java, android

I have this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date result = dateFormat.parse(this.getCreatedTime());
```

Basically I want to convert a string like "2016-09-27T09:19:57Z" into something like "September 27, 2016 at 9:19 AM".

If I use the code above I end up with a `Date` object, but all the methods are deprecated. So how do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you read the Javadocs for the `SimpleDateFormat` class?

Comment: Use another `DateFormat` and format again.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Use `format(dateVarable);` function of `SimpleDateFormat` ...

Comment: You'll need another `DateFormat` (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`) with a different configuration. Then parse your string into a date and format that into a string again. Note that a string is _not_ a date but it can _represent_ one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DateFormat again as @Thomas wrote:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(this.getCreatedTime());
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("outputFormat");
String output = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
```

Comment: Where output format is `MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm a`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should do research before posting any question here.

Use this to get `Date` from your required pattern

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = null;
try {
    date = format.parse(unformattedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Make new instance of your desired patter.

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = format.format(date);
```